# Rootless Network not linked to docker0 interface

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have installed docker in rootless.
When I start my services with docker-compose. When I do docker inspect, the rootless containers are on the network 172.22.0.0/16
But, the host machine network interface docker0 is on 172.17.0.0/16.

Therefore, the rootless containers are not reachable from outside.

My question is, how can I link the rootless network on the docker0 ?